# Angular App Won't Load After Publishing On IE11

Tags: asp.net, angular, internet-explorer, iis

I'm currently developing an app in Angular with an ASP.NET backend. I've configured the project to work fine locally in IE11 (Update polyfills, browserlist, and add ES5 TsConfig files), but when I've published it to the server via IIS the page will not load and is stuck at "Loading..."

To test out publishing I've attempted to publish the default Angular/ASP.NET app to the same results.

The console displays four errors:

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
runtime.458556a34b891ea32398.js (1,1)

SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
polyfills-es5.7119ad0e4b3aeae98a0b.js (1,1)

SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
polyfills.4efda4a4618e08b621be.js (1,1)

SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
main.59969322f93fb24d6bee.js (1,1)
```

*polyfills.ts*

```
import 'classlist.js';
import 'web-animations-js';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

*web.config*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <add value="ClientApp/dist/index.html" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Any errors in browser console?

Comment: @BojanKogoj For some reason I thought I'd checked before and got none, but yes there are four errors. I've updated the question to include them.

Comment: I try to test the issue by creating the ASP.NET Core app with Angular and I just modify the `"target": "es5"` in tsconfig.json file. After that, I try to publish the site to the local folder and host it in IIS by creating a new site. It works fine on my side. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/XOD6Nc4). I suggest you try to make a test by creating a new test app and see whether it works or not. It can give some hint about the issue in your actual app and help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT It must be something with my IIS server, I've been trying this approach and haven't had any luck.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Actually, I did this with the Tour of Heroes Angular app and it worked, the problem has to be with the ASP.Net backend.

Comment: Did you install the **.Net Core runtime** and **Hosting bundle** before hosting the site in the IIS? If not, I suggest you download it according to the version of the .Net Core of your site from [this link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1). After installing it, try to again host your site and see whether it works or not.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I installed the bundle, but unfortunately there are no changes, I'm still stuck at "Loading..."

Comment: @JamesE, I want to confirm with you whether you are using the polyfills that you had included in the polyfills.ts file? If you are not actually using them in your app then just for testing purposes, can you try to comment on it and see whether it makes any difference or not.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT After looking more into it, it seems I actually hadn't installed the Hosting Bundle (I didn't notice the big "Hosting Bundle" link and only downloaded one of the individual parts of the bundle). Now the Angular parts of the site show correctly, but it seems like it can't reach the backend and isn't getting info from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Deepak-MSFT for the answer, turns out I didn't have the [.NET Hosting Bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1) installed on the host machine. Once I installed that, the website displayed as it was supposed to -- barring a couple issues not related to what I'm talking about here.

For those curious, I was having issues with database connection string, I found another project being hosted on the server and modified its connection string:
`data source=[database];initial catalog=[table];persist security info=True;user id=[user id];password=[password];MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework`

I also removed the `web.config` file I'd created, as it would probably get in the way of the one generated during publishing.

Answer (score 0):

your application may throw errors in IE11, even when it is working fine in other browsers. There can be numerous reasons why your Angular application is not working, including:

- Missing polyfills in `polyfills.ts`.
- Using a TypeScript target version which IE11 does not support
- Importing third-party dependencies using a TypeScript target version
  which IE11 does not support

Refer this : https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-fix-your-angular-app-when-its-not-working-in-ie11-eb24cb6d9920

Comment: Unfortunately I've already done all of these steps, I've updated the polyfills and targeted ES5. The app works perfectly fine locally, the issue is only when it's hosted on the IIS server.