# Angular application working with IE11 locally but not when hosted on IIS

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, .net-core-3.1

I have made my angular application (using .NET Core 3.1) compatible with IE11 based on the steps described in this tutorial:
https://dev.to/coly010/angular-how-to-support-ie11-4924

It runs just fine in IE11 when running it locally (Debug or Release mode both work) but after publishing and hosting it on an IIS webserver, it shows a blank page when opening it in IE11.
When inspecting the IE11 console, the following errors are displayed ("Bezeichner erwartet" means "identifier expected"):

[image: IE11errors]

How can I figure out what is wrong here so that I can get the application working in IE11 both locally and when hosted on IIS?

Answer (score 0):

I find [a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64665296/angular-app-wont-load-after-publishing-on-ie11) with the same issue as yours, you can refer to it.

I think your issue might also be not installing **.Net Core runtime** or **Hosting bundle** before hosting the site on IIS. As you are using .NET Core 3.1, I suggest that you can download them from [this link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1) and install them. After installing, please try to host your site on IIS again to see if it can work well.

Comment: The hosting bundle is already installed and the site works just fine in all browsers except IE when hosting it on IIS. The problem is only related to IE and not about hosting the site on IIS in general.

Comment: Have you checked if the document mode is 11 in IE? You can also refer to [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16372). If you create a new Angular app and host it on IIS, can it work well in IE11? I suggest that you can provide steps to reproduce the issue, so that we can have a test and see how to help.

Comment: I checked the document mode and after changing it to 11 it in fact seems to be working! However, when running the site in the actual IE 11 it still doesn't work for some reason. What could be the problem here?

Comment: I guess the default document mode in your IE is not 11. Are you running the hosting website in IE 11 with compatibility mode? Please check the [Compatibility View Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUoZ2.png) in your IE and make sure to uncheck **Display intranet sites in Compatibility View** and make sure your hosting website is not in the Compatibility View site list.